# How do I ask Owin/Katana to write headers to the output stream?

Tags: c#, stream, owin, katana

When I write to the response, Katana skips sending out the Elapsed-Time response header. How can I have it set the headers for me before I write to the stream for the first time?

### Middleware #1

```
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        stopwatch.Stop();

        context.Response.Headers.Add("Elapsed-Time", new[] {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()});
    }
```

### Middleware #2

```
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("test");
    }
```

Comment: The headers are sent when you call Write, so calling Add later doesn't do anything. Try context.Response.OnSendingHeaders

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some research, the answer is that settings headers needs to happen from within OnSendingHeaders. This ensures that the headers are set before the output stream is written to. For example:

```
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(x =>
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Processing-Time", new[] {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()});
        }, null);

        stopwatch.Start();
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Response`'s `Headers` property.

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", <somelength>);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("test");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your Middlewares looks correct. Perhaps, you have issue in the configuration.

Check, if you have pipelined your middleawres like this:

```
app.Use(typeof(MiddlewareOne))
   .Use(typeof(MiddlewareTwo));
```

By the way, you haven't necessity of two midlewares. This will work as wall:

```
public class MyMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public MyMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {}

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("test");
        stopwatch.Stop();

        context.Response.Headers.Add("Elapsed-Time", new[] {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()});
    }
}
```

and configuration is:

```
app.Use(typeof(MyMiddleware));
```

Comment: usually that works for me, but for some reason it's not working now. I've added more info to my question. Hopefully it will help find a solution. Thanks!