# How to work around "A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route template."

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

If I have a controller with an action method that uses attribute based routing and declare it like this, all is well:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/dev/info/{*somevalue}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string somevalue) {

        return View();
    }
```

I can route to the above action method for example by specifying a url that ends in `/dev/info/hello-world` or `/dev/info/new-world`

However my business requirement is to have a urls that look like this: `/dev/hello-world/info` or `/dev/new-world/info`  And there is an endless set of such urls that all need to route to the same action method on the controller.

I thought to set up the attribute based route on the action method as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/dev/{*somevalue}/info/")]
    public IActionResult Get(string somevalue) {

        return View();
    }
```

But when I do that I get the following error as soon as the web project runs:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   RouteCreationException: The following errors occurred with attribute routing information:
>
> For action: 'App.SomeController.Get (1-wwwSomeProject)'
>   Error: A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route template.
>   Parameter name: routeTemplate
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute.GetRouteInfos(IReadOnlyList actions)

There has to be some way to work around this error.  Know a way?

Comment: Do you need to include the `'/'` character in your parameter? Neither of the examples you've shown include it.

Comment: @RichardDeeming The two examples that I provide of how the end can be a wildcard don't need a / to work.  The whole trailing part of the url can be anything (ie ending in a / or not).  But the example of what I'd like to be able to do does end in a / and I really need it to be able to end in a /

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to achieve this by using the regular expression:

```cs
[HttpGet]        
[Route(@"/dev/{somevalue:regex(^.*$)}/info/")]
public IActionResult Get(string somevalue)
{
    return View();
}
```

About routing constrain using the regular expressions see in the documentation: [Route constraint reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraint-reference)

The regular expression tokens explanation:

| Token | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| ^ | Asserts position at start of a line |
| . | Matches any character (except for line terminators) |
| * | Matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible |
| $ | Asserts position at the end of a line |

---

If it's required to have the `“world”`suffix in the second segment then add this suffix to the pattern like the following: `[Route(@"/dev/{somevalue:regex(^.*world$)}/info/")]`.

Answer (score 2):

[Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is the way to achieve this.

If you need an api response is easy to implement inline.

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Path);
        if (context.Request.Path.ToString().EndsWith("/info"))
        {
            // some logic
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Terminal Middleware.");
            return;
        }

        await next(context);
    });
}
```

If you need to call a controller you can simply edit request path via middleware to achieve your requirement.

You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010787/3120219

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me (using .NET 5).

Answer (score 0):

Just helping anyone else having this issue with a **Razor Pages** app - if using a regex string matching pattern to load a Razor Page endpoint, be sure to add this little guy here in your Startup.cs, or top-level file, or whatever Microsoft is doing whenever you're reading this:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // Add as many of these as you'd like
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Path/To/Razor/Template", "/{somevalue}/info");
});
```

Last note: if using a regex in your route logic, Microsoft warns to use a regex timeout, lest the webpage would be vulnerable to regex DDOS attacks.  One way to achieve this is described by this [Stack Overflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67630289)