# How to set match timeout of regex in route attribute of asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, ddos

MSDN recommends setting a time-out value in all regular expression pattern-matching operations.

How we can set match timeout in route attribute of asp.net core projects

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]/{test:regex(^(\\w+$)}")]
public string Get(string test)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to the following sample to [create a custom route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-route-constraints), then, set the Timeout.

```
Public class MyCustomConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private Regex _regex;

    public MyCustomConstraint()
    {
        _regex = new Regex(@"^[1-9]*$",
                            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    }
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey,
                      RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out object value))
        {
            var parameterValueString = Convert.ToString(value,
                                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (parameterValueString == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return _regex.IsMatch(parameterValueString);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, register the above constraint in the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddRouting(options =>
    {
        options.ConstraintMap.Add("customName", typeof(MyCustomConstraint));
    });
}
```

Then, apply the constrain in the action method, like this:

```
// GET /api/test/my/3
[HttpGet("my/{id:customName}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo(id);
}
```

The debug screenshot like this:

[image]

Besides, you can also set the timeout value for all Regex matching operations in an application domain by calling the [AppDomain.SetData method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matchtimeout?view=net-5.0), code in the Program.cs file:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        // Set a timeout interval of 200 milliseconds.
        domain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

Then, there is no need to set the timeout in the custom route constraint, check this screenshot:

[image]